# Gradle copy from non project path

Tags: tomcat, gradle, copy

I wish to copy some files from a non-project location (i.e. somewhere just on file system) however I can't seem to find a way to do it anywhere.

I have tried it like following, where '/file/path/here' is anything like:
/phil/3rd/apache-tomcat/7.0.42/common/conf/catalina.properties
c:/phil/3rd/apache-tomcat/7.0.42/common/conf/catalina.properties
/phil/3rd/apache-tomcat/7.0.42/common/conf, then specify includes 'catalina.properties'
/cygdrive/c/phil/3rd/apache-tomcat/7.0.42/common/conf/catalina.properties (I am running on cygwin)

```
from ('/file/path/here') {
    into 'ui/conf/'
    fileMode = 0644
}
into "$destDir/common"
```

But I get this error:

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'philproject'.

> Could not find method from() for arguments [C:\jpm\ro\3rd\apache-tomcat\7.0.42\common\conf\catalina.properties, build_39gol5r7iv8co45a6o1mh0srpf$_run_closure10_closure42@2a08d18c] on root project

Have tried many different paths and tried to find other ways to copy but to no avail. Can anyone please advise? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show all related code, not just the `from` and `into`. (You can't have these at the top level of a build script, you need a `copy` method or `Copy` task.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can indeed copy from non-project paths with Gradle. Not entirely sure what I was doing wrong, but I couldn't find online whether you can copy from non-project paths so hopefully this will help someone who needs to know.

I found that on windows you need to specify the Absolute path including drive e.g. C:/... , even when using Cygwin...as instead of treating path as absolute (/a/b/c) it treats it asa relative, whereas on Linux it treats /a/b/c as absolute (I guess it's clever enough to figure out if it's relative or absolute).